# How to create array of object from values of another variable in php?

Tags: php

**Working Code:**

```
$node1 = new stdClass();
$node1->field_granule_comments1['und'][0]['value'] = "test";
print_r($node1);
```

**Result**

```
stdClass Object
(
    [field_x] => Array
        (
            [und] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [value] => test
                        )
                )

        )

)
```

I need output like this but I have value in a variable. For example:

```
$id="field_x['und'][0]['value']";
$node2 = new stdClass();
$node2->$id ="test";
print_r($node2);
```

**Output of this code is :**

```
stdClass Object
(
    [field_x['und'][0]['value']] => test
)
```

How can I come up with output similar to "Working Result", taking the value from the variable ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$id="field_x['und'][0]['value']";
$node2 = new stdClass();
$node2->{$id} ="test";
print_r($node2);
```

Enclose the `$id` variable variable within curly brackets.

Comment: I don't see any difference in output. Actually I already tried it before.

Comment: what version of php are you running?

Comment: I am using php 5.3.13

Comment: I don't think it's possible to use multidimensional variable variables to set properties within the class :-s I've been playing around with it and I can set single level variable variables, but not multidimensional ones, I'll have a play around and see if I can update my answer